# Add Attribute to existing Element by passing as parameter in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am adding an attribute to the existing xml using XSLT. I can able to achieve with the fixed values. But want to pass the required data as parameters instead of hard coding it. What I did till now is below.

Input XML :

```
<Student id='5' name="John" />
```

My XSLT code looks like below :

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xml>           

        <xsl:call-template name="Copy" >                                    
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xml>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Student/@age">
    <xsl:attribute name="age">
        <xsl:value-of select="'98'"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="Student">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="age">
            <xsl:value-of select="'45'"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="Copy" match="node()|@*">    
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Output is :

```
<xml><Student age="45" id="5" name="John"/></xml>
```

Now my question is instead of Harcoding the value I need to pass it as a parameter using `<xsl:with-param />` but I am not getting the output as expected. Can anyone help me so.

**Update :**
I will be getting the parameter from other xml which I am going to read, for now I added one variable like below :

```
        <xsl:variable name="attributeValue" >
            <xsl:value-of select="'NewData'"/>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:call-template name="Copy" >
            <xsl:with-param name="AttributeValue">
                <xsl:value-of select="$attributeValue"/>
            </xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
```

Comment: From where does the parameter value come?

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed I updated my question.

I will be getting that from other xml, for now we can create one variable like mentioned in the question (updated) and that variable I want to pass as parameter

Answer (score 0):

If you know where to look up the values in the "other XML", you can use a global variable instead of a parameter, and avoid all the `<xsl:with-param>` elements. For example, if the other XML looks like

```xml
<OtherData>
  <Age>45</Age>
  ...
</OtherData>
```

you can write

```xml
<xsl:variable name="attributeValue" select="document('http://path/to/other/xml')//Age"/>
```

at the top level of your transformation. Then it will be available as `$attributeValue` in all templates.

Comment: my question was not how to read **age** value,  its about how to pass the value to the template so that the existing functionality won't break. Currently if I pass it , Value is not reflecting in the final output. :(

Comment: I have tried to clarify this in my edited answer.